# How do I remove someone’s links from embedded YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I want to embed a YouTube video to my website.

The uploader included a floating link to his website at the corner of the video.

Is there a way to remove it with some parameter?

Comment: If you include a link to the video, it would be easier to see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the annotations, you can disable them by setting `iv_load_policy` to 3.

> **iv_load_policy** (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5)
>   Values: 1 or 3. Default is 1. Setting to 1 will cause video annotations to be shown by default, whereas setting to 3 will cause video annotation to not be shown by default.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#iv_load_policy).